# Return nil instead of undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when having array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following @params where `people` is an array of objects.
`{"people"=>[{"email"=>"sample1@google.com"}, {"email"=>"sample@google.com"}]}`

I am looking for a way to get back `nil` instead of the undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass error when I try to access `@params[:people][0][:email]` when any of the emails or people are not present or if @params[:people] has an empty array and we try to get the email.

I found that we could use `@params.dig(:people)` but I would like to know how I can consider the array `[0]` and achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do the job:

```
@params.dig(:people, 0, :email)
```

Example:

```
params = { people: [{ email: 'foo@example.com' }] }
params.dig(:people, 0, :email)
#=> "foo@example.com"

params = { people: [] }
params.dig(:people, 0, :email)
#=> nil
```